# Gradient colors for a series of scatter data

Tags: python, colors, scatter

I have 100 groups of array, in which each of them contains 4 data points. I would like to plot these 100 data series but for different 100 colors. I hope the colors are gradient. To make it clear, i would like 100 gradient colors for these 100 data series.

```
y=np.random.rand(1, 400).reshape(100,4)
x=np.linspace(0.3,6.3,num=4,endpoint=True)                  

for j in range(100):                                

    x_final=[x[k]+j*0.01 for k in range(4)]
    y_final=y[j,:]

    plt.scatter(x_final, y_final)
plt.show()
```